# XBMC green lines on 10.7.4

Tags: macos

After upgrade my system to 10.7.4, the XBMC Eden (latest version) shows green lines all over the screen.

Does anybody have this issue?

Comment: Have you asked on the [XBMC Mac OS X support forum](http://forum.xbmc.org/forumdisplay.php?fid=56)? You might get better results there.

Comment: Have you tried changing changing "De-interlace method" from "de-interlace" to "auto select"?

Answer (score 1):

turning off hardware acceleration (VDVDecoder) seemed to fix it